# Authorization to exclude Home Page - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a authorization scheme applied to the properties of the application that returns

```
RETURN MYFUNCTION(:APP_USER, :APP_PAGE_ID);
```

The issue is, it does not let the user login when the home page ID doesn't return. How can I apply the scheme to the application excluding home page?

I'm using Apex 19.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your function would look something like this, with an added if statement for your problem at hand.

```
begin
  -- exclusions for this page check
  if p_page_id in (
    101 -- login page
   ,1   -- home page
  ) then
    return true;
  end if;

  -- does user have access to the page provided?
  select count(*)
  into l_exists
  from dual
  where exists
    (select null
     from sec_table
     where page_id = p_page_id
     and username = p_app_user
  );
  return l_exists = 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understood you correctly, but - `myfunction` should be created so that it accepts exactly two parameters, and their names must be `p_username` and `p_password`. It is supposed to return Boolean:

- `true` if credentials are OK and you're allowed to connect
- `false`, if the opposite

It seems that your function returns *home page ID*; is that correct? If so, well, I just told you what to do. If not, could you, please, explain what you mean by

> when the home page ID doesn't return

and

> how can I apply the scheme (...) excluding home page

Comment: My function returns true for all the Page Ids except Home Page ID as it is not in the sql table. I don't want to assign home page individually to every user. I want it to be displayed to every authenticated users regardless of the authorization scheme.

Comment: Myfuction is already created which checks the table and return true for pages assigned to user.

Comment: well... it does return false when it should return true so... start debugging your pl/sql code. You can do this in apex by adding calls to apex_debug.info (check doc for syntax) in your function body to check what parameters are passed. This should show you why it is not working the way you want and then you can decide how to fix it...